# What's your development/deployment pipeline/workflow while working with version control systems?

Tags: svn, deployment

Right now, in my working environment, we use SVN both for our scripts development and deployment. For each script project, there are at least 2 separated repositories on SVN: one for **dev** and the other for **dep**.

Our workflow as following:

- developing in **dev** repo w/o any constraints.
- when everything is done and approved, gather some files and commit them into **dep** repo. They are different for files in **dev** repo and **dep** repo. Ex, the .py files in **dev** repo and .pyc files for **dep** repo.
- the structure of **dep** repo is exactly the same to the final deployment.
- therefore, we can just switch to the authorized account and do **svn up dep_repo** to deployment them.

The idea behind is:

- separate the development and deployment
- allow as much freedom as possible for development
- also track the history of deployment
- allow the difference of structure between **dev** and **dep**

But we still think the workflow is some sorta in-convenience. 1) You have to manually gather files and commit them into **dep** repo; 2) You have to swtich to the authorized account to do the final deployment.

I know we can make use of hooks to automate the 2nd issue but I am not sure if that's a good way to do. Any thoughts or ideas to share about your workflow for a group of programmers?

Answer (score 0):

You would be much better served to use the branch and merge features of SVN to manage the differences between your development line of code and your deployment line of code. This way, you can track changes over time to the files, as well as have an easy way to fix bugs.

Also, since it sounds like you are tracking compiled (or the equivalent) files in your current `dep` repo, by tracking the built artifacts along with the code they are built from, you can more closely track what changes have gone into each release (without manually picking the files)